# Duvidas a respeito de DAO, MVC, Multiplas Tabelas e POJO

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, mvc, padrão-dao, pojo

Se alguem puder me ajudar, tenho uma duvida q vem me consumindo muito nos últimos dias e esta travando psicologicamente meus estudos (hehehhe) MVC e DAO com múltiplas tabelas.
Vou colocar aqui um modelo, uma ideia e depois evoluir minhas dúvidas:

Imaginamos um sistema de comparação de preços entre produtos que um usuário insere os dados para que seja feito o processo de comparação:

Segue o esquema dos dados, o modelo logico do banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela item tem relação com Unidade já que o item pode ter Unidade de Medida diferentes.

A tabela item também se liga a tabela Itens Comparados que por sua vez se liga a Compara.

Tenho a tabela Itens Comparados pois uma comparação pode ser feita com vários itens.

Segue também meus pacotes com as classes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo:

Manteiga A – 250 g, R$3,25

Manteiga B – 180 g, R$ 2,80

Preciso saber qual das duas é mais barata, para isso preciso saber o valor de cada grama da manteiga A e B, assim vou saber exatamente qual é a mais barata.

Minhas principais dúvidas são o seguinte:

1 – MVC – Model, View e Controller, pois bem:

- Model = São meus modelos de negócio como eu tenho cálculos para realizar sobre determinados itens, eu teria dentro de Model uma classe chamada Comparacao que vai receber os objetos que tem relação Item – ItensComparados – Compara.

Realmente Model serve para isso? 
Vejo muitas pessoas colocando aqui os objetos POJO (Carro, Posto, Locadora...)

- View = Não tenho duvidas!!!
- Controller = Serve para intermediar a view com o banco (DAO). No caso de usar esse conceito no Android seria para controllar as listas e inserções nas diversas tabelas que os relacionamentos necessitam? No caso eu vou juntar dentro do controller_comparacao por exemplo o processo de inserção de cada entidade e os IDs gerados pelas inserções colocarei dentro da tabela Compara juntamente com os ItensComparados?

2 - DAO - Data Access Object

- Como falei no Model do MVC vejo muitas pessoas criando dentro da pasta model objetos POJO, eu acredito que o correto seria criar um pacote com nome POJO, VO, PO por exemplo e criar suas entidades lá isso auxila no DAO, esta correto eu pensar assim?
- Quando crio um objeto POJO como por exemplo Item, ele possui:

  public class Item {

  ```
  Integer _item_id;
  String item_descricao;
  Float item_preco;
  Float item_quantidade;
  Float item_preco_unidade;
  String item_cod_barras;
  Integer fk_unidade_medida;
  ```

  ...
  }

Qual a melhor forma de se construir esses POJOs com relação a ligação com outra entidade (Relacionamento). Uso uma Integer como no exemplo acima OU:

```
public class Item {

        Integer _item_id;
        String item_descricao;
        Float item_preco;
        Float item_quantidade;
        Float item_preco_unidade;
        String item_cod_barras;
        UnidadeMedida unidade_medida;

    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, Hugo!

Bem pelo descrição eu não entendi, mas pela sua modelagem e do domínio do seu projeto acho que posso ajudá-lo.

MVC - Existe muita confusão, muitos autores falando abobrinhas sobre o tempo e acaba confundindo nossa cabeça. O modelo diz respeito às regras de negócio, isso inclui, o os pojos que é a mesma coisa que model, também inclui o business que é onde de fato devem ficar as regras de negócio, cálculos, DAOs etc. A visão ou View é literalmente as páginas e não ficam necessariamente nos pacotes da aplicação. Já o Controller ou controlador é um papel que pode ser desempenhado tanto por você quando pelo servidor de aplicação ou pelo framework que estiver utilizando, isso é o tratamento das requisições. Simples. Mas todo mundo cria uma arquitetura de um jeito conforme o entendimento desses conceitos.

Mapeamento ORM - Pelo seu domínio (projeto) achei meio confuso esse modelo de dados (tabelas). Mas eu faria assim: criaria uma entidade Item com os atributos id, nome, estabelecimento e preço. Uma entidade Categoria com id, descricao e outra ItensComparados com id, item, categoria.

Assim você compara os itens de uma categoria e armazena na tabela itenscomparados de acordo com a categoria. Deu pra entender?

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre MVC:

- **View**: Somente visualizações. É recomendado que seja tipada - `@model`, e nunca deve ter regras de negócio nesta camada - isso inclui qualquer condicional, como `if`, `switch`, etc. Se for necessário, crie um `HtmlHelper`, crie seus testes e depois apenas faça a chamada a partir da *View*.
- **Controller**: É a camada mais ***BURRA*** da sua aplicação. Ela apenas cuida de receber uma requisição, transferir a chamada para a `Action` responsável, então essa `Action` apenas passa esses dados para demais camadas de negócio processarem essas informações. Após o processamento, a *Action Controller* receber de volta um resultado e devolve para a View. Não deve haver qualquer tipo de regra de negócio dentro da *Action Controler*, pois não é de sua responsabilidade.
- **Model**: Representa as entidades que sua aplicação irá trabalhar. Algo como seus *POJO*'s. Tanto que, quanto tipamos uma *View*, usamos a marcação `@model` para isso. Então, *Model* representa as entidades modelo de sua aplicação.

*Model* é onde, comumente, se diz que ficam as regras de negócio. Mas dizer isso é o mesmo que dizer que *View* são as páginas, *Controller* são as ações da página e *Model* é todo o resto.

E isso é apenas para criar sua aplicação web. As regras em si devem ser contruídas em outros projetos/camadas, cada um com sua responsablidade. E essas outras camadas, nada tem a ver com MVC.

Tendo suas camadas de regras, modelos, infraestrutura, repositórios, todas segregadas e desaclopadas, estas podem ser usadas em uma aplicação MVC, aplicação Desktop, UWP, *CommandPrompt*, etc.

Algo que eu recomendo é criar uma `ClassLibrary` apenas para suas entidades modelos. Outra para suas regras, outra para repositórios. Todas desacopladas.

[Tenho um projeto no GitHub que pode te servir de modelo para começar](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD). Já está um poco datado, mas ainda  é um ótimo começo.

Sobre DAO:

Suas entidades modelo devem refletir a realidade.

```
public class Produto 
{
    int Id { get; set; } 
    string Descricao { get; set; } 
    UnidaDeMedida UnidadeDeMedida { get; set; }
    decimal Quantidade { get; set; } 
    decimal PrecoPorUnidade { get; set; } 
    string CodigoDeBarras { get; set; } 
    // ...
}
```